NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: with signals
I randomly have this error ( that I understand the importance of after research ) but I don't understand how to avoid it.
I have an api service with a number Signals initially set to 0 that I update to +1 at each http query, and update -1 at each response/error
showProgressBar = signal(0)
...

public request( request: object ): Observable<any> {
      this.showProgressBar.update(t => t+1)
      return this.#_http.post<any>...

}

and a simple componant that check the signals and display a loading animation on the screen when >0
@Component({
  selector: 'app-api-loading',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatProgressBarModule],
  templateUrl: `
  @if ( _api.showProgressBar()>0 ) {
    <mat-progress-bar mode="query" class="bottomOfScreen"/>
  }
`,
  styleUrl: './api-loading.component.scss'
})
export class ApiLoadingComponent {
  _api = inject(ApiService)

}


I don't understand how I can have the control on when the signal is changed or not.
I mean how can I prevent the signal to be change out of the lifecycle of the component to prevent this error?

Are you sure the error comes exactly from that component and in relation to the signal? Sidenote: the name showProgressBar is very irritating as it indicates a boolean value Kindly rename it to progressBarCounter for example. You could add another computed signal showProgressBar which then is a boolean and can be consumed.

I am unable to reproduce the error with the given code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-tfyho3?file=src%2Fmain.ts
